# Delay/Pause Slick Slide Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I'm trying to create a carousel on my website using [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

On my website, I have a specific button which the user can select that will slide the carousel to the next section:

```
<button class="right-answer" onclick="showResult(this)">3</button>
```

This button uses the following line to make the transition:

```
function showResult(b) {
    if (b.classList.contains('right-answer')) {
        $(".qa").slick('slickNext')
    }
    else { ... }
}
```

This is similar to how the navigation arrows work in the [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) demonstrations.

How can I make it so that when the user selects the button (which runs the code above), it will wait 5 seconds before executing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**setTimeout()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

```
$('button').click(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".qa").slick('slickNext')
}, 5000);
});
```